# Read Excel with multiple headers and unnamed column

Tags: python, pandas

I recieve some Excel files like that :

```
      USA            UK     
      plane   cars   plane  cars    
2016  2       7      1      3     # a comment after the last country
2017  3       1      8      4
```

There is an unknown amount of countries and there can be a comment after the last column.

When I read the Excel file like that...

```
df = pd.read_excel(
    sourceFilePath,
    sheet_name = 'Sheet1',
    index_col = [0],
    header = [0, 1]
)
```

... I have a value error :

```
ValueError: Length of new names must be 1, got 2
```

The problem is I cannot use the usecols param because I don't know how many countries there is before reading my file.

How can I read such a file ?

Comment: Have you tried `headers = [0, 1]`? Note the plural 's',

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible Pandas won't be able to fix your special use case, but you can write a program that fixes the spreadsheet using [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). It has really clear documentation, but here's an overview of how to use it:

```
import openpyxl as xl

wb = xl.load_workbook("ExampleSheet.xlsx")

for sheet in wb.worksheets:
    print("Sheet Title => {}".format(sheet.title))
    print("Dimensions => {}".format(sheet.dimensions)) # just returns a string
    print("Columns: {} <-> {}".format(sheet.min_column, sheet.max_column))
    print("Rows: {} <-> {}".format(sheet.min_row, sheet.max_row))
    for r in range(sheet.min_row, sheet.max_row + 1):
        for c in range(sheet.min_column, sheet.max_column + 1):
            if (sheet.cell(r,c).value != None):
                print("Cell {}:{} has value {}".format(r,c,sheet.cell(r,c).value))
```

Answer (score 0):

what about just using `pd.read_csv`?

once loaded, you can then determine how many columns you have with `df.columns`